# algorithm title, which is unnumbered, is not in place

Tags: algorithm2e

The code

```
\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\TitleOfAlgo{SA}
\BlankLine
\KwData{Movie}
\KwResult{Classification}
\BlankLine
\Begin
{    
\textbf{call Function 1: S}\\
\textbf{call Function 2: St}\\
\textbf{call Function 3: Su}\\
\textbf{call Function 4: Un}\\
}       
\end{algorithm}
```

gives the output as desired but the title is not correctly placed. I mean it is not coming inbetween, two ruled lines. It is appearing after two ruled lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the `ruled` option for [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e), you'll have to use `\caption` in order to place the name of the algorithm between the lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \SetAlgoLined
  \caption{SA}
  \BlankLine
  \KwData{Movie}
  \KwResult{Classification}
  \BlankLine
  \Begin
  {    
    \textbf{call Function 1: S}\;
    \textbf{call Function 2: St}\;
    \textbf{call Function 3: Su}\;
    \textbf{call Function 4: Un}\;
  }     
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

This does number the algorithm when printing it, as you can see above. If you don't want this to happen, then you can use the following setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\RemoveAlgoNumber}{\renewcommand{\fnum@algocf}{\AlCapSty{\AlCapFnt\algorithmcfname}}}
\newcommand{\RevertAlgoNumber}{\algocf@resetfnum}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\RemoveAlgoNumber

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption*{SA}
  \BlankLine
  \KwData{Movie}
  \KwResult{Classification}
  \BlankLine
  \Begin
  {    
    \textbf{call Function 1: S}\;
    \textbf{call Function 2: St}\;
    \textbf{call Function 3: Su}\;
    \textbf{call Function 4: Un}\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I use [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) which provides `\caption*` (for ease-of-use) that doesn't increment the respective float counter (`algocf` in this case). I also defined two macros:

- `\RemoveAlgoNumber` which removes `\thealgocf` from the caption printing; and
- `\RevertAlgoNumber` which reverts the removal.

You can also define your own caption style/format via the `algorithm2e` internals to achieve the above.

Comment: As u can see from the above code, i want to name this algorithm as MAIN ALGORITHM and unnumbered and then another four algorithms which should be numbered as 1, 2, 3, 4 and with name Function 1....4.  But with your code, either all are coming unnumbered or after reverting, Function is starting with Function 2 instead of Function 1.

Comment: @userjha: Are you using `\caption*` for the first algorithm like in my example?

Comment: No, i m using \TitleOfAlgo for first algorithm, which is main algorithm in my case and for all the functions, Functions1.....4, i m using \caption and there is no problem in numbering, first is unnumbered and others are numbered. Only thing is Main Algorithm is not placing correctly between the lines.

Comment: @userjha: My suggestion is to use `\caption*` like in my example for your main/first algorithm. What's wrong with that?

Comment: If i am using \caption*  then this is making my functions also unnumbered. If i am using \RevertAlgoNumber as u said then the functions are starting from number 2, but i want it to start from number 1.  More over my code is like below:

Comment: \documentclass{article}      \usepackage{caption}      \usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}      \makeatletter \renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{MAIN ALGORITHM} \newcommand{\RemoveAlgoNumber}{\renewcommand{\fnum@algocf}{\AlCapSty{\AlCapFnt\a‌​lgorithmcfname}}} \newcommand{\RevertAlgoNumber}{\algocf@resetfnum} \makeatother      \begin{algorithm}      \caption*{SA}      \BlankLine      \KwData{Movie}      \KwResult{Classification} \BlankLine \Begin { \textbf{call Function 1: S}\; \textbf{call Function 2: St}\; \textbf{call Function 3: Su}\; \textbf{call Function 4: Un}\; } \end{algorithm}

Comment: This gives the output as MAIN ALGORITHM : * in first line and the name of algorithm i.e. SA in second line.

Comment: @userjha: [This is what your code should look like](http://pastebin.com/jDvdyCCm). You need a `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, and appropriate use of `\RemoveAlgoNumber` and/or `\RevertAlgoNumber`.